# Android Cling streaming local audio files to Renderer

Tags: android, upnp, android-cling

I am writing an app that allows streaming of Media from the Phone to a Media Renderer.

I am using Cling for the UPNP integration and now I am starting to get abit confused.

If I want to stream the Music from my Phone do I have to write both a MediaServer and a ControlPoint in my App where the ControlPoint than accesses the Server and sends the URL to the Renderer?

Or is there a better / easier way to achieve this f.e. just accessing the files on the Phone and somehow making only a selected file available for streaming therefore just using a Controller and no MediaServer on the Phone?

Comment: You'd only need to implement MediaServer if you want other control points to browse the files you offer.  If this isn't required, you just need to implement a HTTP server that the renderer can contact to request the file(s) you've instructed it to play.